# Traverse a graph using multiple schema criteria in Gremlin

Tags: graph, gremlin

I'm trying to make a Gremlin query to traverse a graph containing people and places. The query needs to get the counting of person-looking-each-other. Supposing it was already collected and processed by an image algorithm. Please see the dummy graph below.

```
g.addV('local').as('1').
  property(single, 'cidade', 'Londres').
  property(single, 'rua', 'Oxford').
  addV('pessoa').as('2').
  property(single, 'idade', 25).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Liam').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('3').
  property(single, 'idade', 45).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Preston').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('4').
  property(single, 'idade', 25).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Lexie').
  property(single, 'genero', 'F').
  addV('pessoa').as('5').
  property(single, 'idade', 45).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Toby').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('6').
  property(single, 'idade', 52).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Sam').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('7').
  property(single, 'idade', 32).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Jack').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('8').
  property(single, 'idade', 29).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Lola').
  property(single, 'genero', 'F').
  addV('pessoa').as('9').
  property(single, 'idade', 51).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Bella').
  property(single, 'genero', 'F').
  addV('pessoa').as('10').
  property(single, 'idade', 37).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Dalilah').
  property(single, 'genero', 'F').
  addV('pessoa').as('11').
  property(single, 'idade', 28).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Oliver').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('12').
  property(single, 'idade', 21).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Peter').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addV('pessoa').as('13').
  property(single, 'idade', 18).
  property(single, 'nome', 'Tyler').
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').addV('local').
    as('14').
  property(single, 'rua', 'Atlântica').
  property(single, 'cidade', 'Rio de Janeiro').
  addV('pessoa').as('15').
  property(single, 'nome', 'Marta').
  property(single, 'idade', 24).
  property(single, 'genero', 'F').
  addV('pessoa').as('16').
  property(single, 'nome', 'Jorge').
  property(single, 'idade', 18).
  property(single, 'genero', 'M').
  addE('olhou-para').from('2').to('4').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('2').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('3').to('4').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('3').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('4').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('5').to('4').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('5').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('6').to('4').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('6').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('7').to('9').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('7').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('8').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('9').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('10').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('11').to('10').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('11').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('12').to('8').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('12').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('13').to('8').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('13').to('1').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('15').to('14').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('caminhando-em').from('16').to('14').
  property('data_hora', '4-7-21 8:31:23').
  addE('olhou-para').from('16').to('15')
```

The words are in Portuguese, "caminhando-em" means "walking-on", meaning that a person is walking on a specific Street. The edges "olhou-para" mean "stared", meaning that a person looked to another person on that place. The objective is "measure" the beauty of a person based on the look of the others. I don't know if the term "stared" is appropriate in English to express this.

The query below works to get the look counting aggregated by person who received the looking.

```
g.V().
inE("olhou-para").
group().by(inV().values("nome")).unfold().
project("pessoa","count").
by(select(keys)).
by(select(values).count(local)).
order().by("count",Order.desc)
```

The results are:

```
[
  {
    "pessoa": "Lexie",
    "count": 4
  },
  {
    "pessoa": "Lola",
    "count": 2
  },
  {
    "pessoa": "Marta",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pessoa": "Dalilah",
    "count": 1
  },
  {
    "pessoa": "Bella",
    "count": 1
  }
]
```

The thing is: how to select only the looking from London in a specific data/time?
I mean, how to filter to ignore the "Marta" vertex from "Rio de Janeiro" city?

Thanks in advance,
Julio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could perhaps add an additional filter like this:

```
gremlin> g.V().
......1> inE("olhou-para").
......2> filter(outV().out('caminhando-em').has('cidade','Londres')).
......3> group().by(inV().values("nome")).unfold().
......4> project("pessoa","count").
......5> by(select(keys)).
......6> by(select(values).count(local)).
......7> order().by("count",Order.desc)

==>[pessoa:Lexie,count:4]
==>[pessoa:Lola,count:2]
==>[pessoa:Dalilah,count:1]
==>[pessoa:Bella,count:1]
```